# Как отозвать JWT токен?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

Есть Web приложение с использованием JWT токена. Сайт отдает Access и Refresh токены.

Собственно при использовании RefreshToken'а как я понял нам надо убить все старые AccessToken'ы.

Никак не могу понять, как это сделать на Asp.net Core? Ведь мы их не храним как Refresh, они известны только пользователю.

Можно конечно сохранять все токены в некой таблице:

```
Token | isValid    
00000 | false    
00001 | true
```

И в дальнейшем просто проверять статус токена, но какое то это странное как по мне решение, да и как даже это реализовать, ведь мы должны как то отловить заход пользователя через старый токен...

Comment: Убивать не надо, AcecessToken сам протухнет по таймауту

Comment: @andreymal Хорошо, а если допустим, сменили пароль, токен у нас ну скажем на пол часа, значит эти пол часа мы будем иметь доступ со старым паролем? Как то не очень...

Comment: А это целая тема для длинных дискуссий и одна из причин, почему лично я вообще не использую JWT) Решение с хранением токенов в таблице лично мне не кажется странным

Comment: @andreymal Я не против использовать хранение в базе, вопрос только как в последующем проверять его...

Comment: @andreymal Кстати, а что Вы предпочитаете для работы с ресурсом через клиент приложение? Может и я выберу что то другое...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ JWT сам по себе не предполагает возможности "убивать" access-токен, ведь предполагается, что он нигде не хранится (в этом и его большой плюс, за счет своей самодостаточности нет необходимости обращаться к другим сервисам за валидацией токена). Есть два варианта, что можно сделать в вашем случае: 1) Как вы и предполагали, хранить access-токены, но только не в БД, а в кеше. 2) Уменьшить время жизни access-токена. В вашей задаче он должен быть достаточно мал, чтобы у злоумышленника не хватило времени на изменение пароля.

Comment: Интересно узнать, к чему вы по итогу пришли

Comment: @AndreiKhotko К сожалению, тот проект мне пришлось забросить, из-за чего нормального решения я так и не сделал. Временным, была использована база, куда я складывал все токены, ну и делал проверку по типу "есть ли токен в базе".

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете преобразовать токен в модель и обратно с помощью библиотеки 
[Jose-jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jose-jwt).

```
Token newToken = new Token();
EncodeToken(newToken, users);

public partial class Users
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
private static void EncodeToken(Token token, Users users)
{
        var secretKey = new byte[]
        {
            164, 60, 194, 0, 161, 189, 41, 38, 130, 89, 141, 164, 45, 170, 159,
            209, 69, 137, 243, 216, 191, 131, 47, 250, 32, 107, 231, 117, 37, 158, 225, 234
        };

        token.id = users.Id;
        token.Key = Jose.JWT.Encode(users, secretKey, Jose.JwsAlgorithm.HS256);
}

private static Users DecodeToken(string token)
{
   var secretKey = new byte[]
   {
            164, 60, 194, 0, 161, 189, 41, 38, 130, 89, 141, 164, 45, 170, 159, 209,
            69, 137, 243, 216, 191, 131, 47, 250, 32, 107, 231, 117, 37, 158, 225, 234
   };

   var users = Jose.JWT.Decode<Users>(token, secretKey);
   return users;
}
```

Вы можете добавить в класс юзера время действия токена и сверять с текущем временем. Ну или сделать уже другие проверки, необходимые вам(например сверять пароль)

Comment: В Asp.net Core вроде как есть стандартные методы для этого. И вопрос по большей части - "как мне отловить то, что пользователь зашел через JWT", а не "Как раскодировать токен".

Answer (score 0):

Если не надо держать несколько живых токенов одновременно или нужно просрачивать все разом по событию. Я сделал так.

Добавил рядом с паролем поле `serial` в нем храню номер последнего валидного токена

В токен записывается serial не из таблицы, а из общего счетчика.

При проверке авторизации делаю сравнение user.serial <= token.serial

При нажатии кнопки выход или при смене пароля user.serial = token.serial

Если нужно держать только одну сессию, то при получении нового токена обновляю serial

Если нужно каждый токен видеть отдельно - создавай таблицу с номерами активных токенов. Старые помечай на удаление.

Comment: Это подразумевает, что нужно сходить за user.serial в базу, что убивает примерно весь смысл JWT

Comment: @andreymal а по-другому как серверу узнать что ключ отозвали?

Comment: Никак, JWT по природе своей не предназначен для отзыва

Comment: Но если очень хочется, то можно) тем не менее табличка отзыва будет короткой и более быстрой чем поиск пользователя